# Unselect all rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, selection, rows

I have two datagridviews, and when I click to one of them, I would like to deselect all selection in the second datagridview, I tried this, but nothing works:

```
firstItemsDataGridView.ClearSelection();
firstItemsDataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
```

not working,

```
firstItemsDataGridView.ClearSelection();
if (firstItemsDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
    firstItemsDataGridView[1, 0].Selected = true;
firstItemsDataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
firstItemsDataGridView.ClearSelection();
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in firstItemsDataGridView.Rows) {
    item.Selected = false;

    foreach (DataGridViewCell itemCell in firstItemsDataGridView.Columns) {
        itemCell.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

not working,

```
firstItemsDataGridView.Rows[0,-1].Selected = true;
```

not working too.

I have set selecting mode to full row selection, and I have no idea how to achieve my goal.
 thanks a lot!

Comment: is `firstItemsDataGridView` the desired grid ? Are you assigning a DataSource again ?

Comment: firstItemsDataGridView is grid where I need to unselect all items, I am not using any datasources(binding)

Comment: Setting `CurrentCell=null` should do the trick, but then how is the data shown in the grid provided/added ?

Answer (score 82):

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

Should work. Maybe you have code that auto selects rows which is triggered?

Comment: Don't call it too soon!

Comment: Putting it in the dataGridView1.MouseDown event works great

Answer (score 6):

An answer at NullSkull solved the problem for me which was that the cell at row 0, column 0 for the datagridview control was always selected on form load, and could not be deselected despite calling ClearSelection within the form's constructor method.  I just had to call ClearSelection in the Form_Load event.
http://www.nullskull.com/q/10066166/how-to-deselect-the-first-row-when-the-form-i-loaded-in-datagridview-in-windows-application.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no answer, and I used this answer in other posts and i ran into the same issue of first row being selected and deselecting wasn't possible:

```
Color blue  = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCFFFF");
Color red = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCCFF");
Color letters = Color.Black;

foreach (DataGridViewRow r in datagridIncome.Rows)
{
    if (r.Cells[5].Value.ToString().Contains("1")) { 
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = blue;
        r.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = blue;
        r.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = letters;
    }
    else { 
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = red;
        r.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = red;
        r.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = letters;
    }
}
```

This is a small trick, the only way you can see a row is selected, is by the very first column (not column[0], but the one therefore). When you click another row, you will not see the blue selection anymore, only the arrow indicates which row have selected.

***SOLUTION:***

i found out why my first row was default selected and found out how to not select it by default.

By default my datagridview was the object with the first tab-stop on my windows form. Making the tab stop first on another object (maybe disabling tabstop for the datagrid at all will work to) disabled selecting the first row

Comment: dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

dgvName.ClearSelection();

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it's working for me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the rows are deselected (dataGridView.Rows[...].Selected = false)

Row zero defaults to selected, so set dataGridView.Rows[0].Selected = false when opening the DataGridView and as long as the other options are set so the user can't select, then you will have, and maintain, nothing selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
// no selection in dgv at the begening   
dgv.FirstDisplayedCell = null;
dgv.ClearSelection();
// try this it is working !
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using WPF and want to maintain a  MVVM design pattern you can bind both selected items to the same property so when you select one the other will automatically be deselected.

try something like this

```
public class SingletonClass
{
    private static SingletonClass _Instance;
    public static SingletonClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null)
                _Instance = new SingletonClass();
            return _Instance;
        }
    }   // End Property Instance

    private object _SelectedItem;
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set { _SelectedItem = value; }
    } // End Selected Item
 }

<DataGrid Name="Datagrid1" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={x:Static Const:SingletonClass.Instance},Path=SelectedItem,IsAsync=True}">

<DataGrid Name="Datagrid2" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={x:Static Const:SingletonClass.Instance},Path=SelectedItem,IsAsync=True}">
```

*I only used a singleton class because this will work across different views in different instances, you can use a regular class if your in the same view.

Please note the **IsAsync=True** on the xmal, if you plan on using a singleton class across diffrent views it will not work without it.

Answer (score 0):

As said @Taw in subcomments to top answer - **"Don't call it too soon!"**.

In my case default behavior not works at all. My case - **datagrid in tab of tabControl** and it did not work if that tab not shown before!

That hack works like a charm :

```
AnyTabControl.SelectedTab = FirsTab;
gridModules.ClearSelection(); //placed at first tab
AnyTabControl.SelectedTab = SecondTab; //that tab i would like to show first
```

As a result : second tab displayed to user, and when he clicked to first - selection will not appear.